# Is it ok to upload a package to CTAN, where only part of its expected final features are currently available?

Tags: package-writing, ctan

**Context:** I am developing a package that aims at providing a set of several environments and related macros. One environment is currently fully developed.

<sub>(In concrete terms, my package aims at providing an interface on top of Ti*k*Z for easily creating common graphs through a user friendly interface. I have one type of graph (bar chart) ready, and will develop the others (scatter plot, box plot, etc.) in the next few months.)</sub>

**Question:** Should I publish my package now (when only parts of final features are enabled), or is it better to wait until all expected features are developed?

Publishing it now would enable me to already receive feedbacks and ask questions about it. I also could increment features little by little. However, I am not sure how well it would be perceive flood CTAN with frequent package updates and to provide now a package with limited available features.

*Note:* Of course, I will upload only fully working versions on CTAN (and, hopefully, no buggy one). Only the amount of features should increment in new versions. I will also make sure of the retro-compatibility of each future version. (Not that hard, since each feature will be provided through an independent environment.)

Comment: How frequent is 'frequent'? How confident are you of backwards compatibility?

Comment: I'm also interested, since I have a similar problem. My package is 90% working and also will gain features in future. To what extend are bugs acceptable which i havent found yet?

Comment: @cfr I would say that 4/5 new features would be implemented in the next few weeks or months. Regarding backwards compatibility, I'd say I'm rather confident, since each type of graph will be drawn via a dedicated environment.

Answer (score 4):

By no means I have an official guideline, but I recently developed a package and deployed in many steps, before reaching the current state (which is almost final). I might've provided this as a comment but it's way too long

To me the essential is that the features you have released are **stable** and are expected to be **maintained.** There's no point in releasing something that perhaps people will start using and then will be gone.

Also I think that the features to be released would have to be **complete** and **tested**. Of course someone could ask for further developments (yourself may consider it in the future) or find bugs, but I think you should be confident that what you have not only works, but completes a feature conclusively, ie, you will upload new versions when *adding* new features (thus possibly new macros) and not when *completing* the features.

---

To complete an answer, reading your question, I think that **I** would start considering a release if all of the folowing applies:

1. The `barchart` command works and has been tested and thoroughly commented
2. The `barchart` command won't probably updated any time soon (except bugfixing)
3. All of the other features you provide will be in other commands